# fetch navigate event is happening multiple times in offline mode

Tags: javascript, service-worker

When I switch to offline mode in "applications" tab and reload the page "fetch" event with evt.request.mode = 'navigate' fires 2 times and then 1 time after 5 seconds.

My SW code is like this:

```js
function fetchHandler(evt) {
 const waitPromise = fetch(evt.request.url).catch(err => {
  console.log(`${new Date} - error`);
  return Response.error();
 });

 evt.respondWith(waitPromise);
}

self.addEventListener('fetch', evt => {
 console.log('fetch', evt.request.url, evt.request.mode);

 const isFetch = (evt.request.method === 'GET');
 const isNavigate = (evt.request.mode === 'navigate');

 if (isFetch && isNavigate) {
  fetchHandler(evt);
 }
});
```

Is this an expected behaviour or not?

[image]